# Prevent war file from being copied to .m2/repository when running mvn clean install

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-war-plugin

We have a multi-module Maven project and we typically run `mvn clean install` to build everything. Preferably, we'd like to keep it this way.

What we would like to do is prevent projects with packaging `war` (that are using the `maven-war-plugin`) to copy their generated war files to the `~/.m2/repository` folder. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how this is done in an answer and then I'll accept it?

Comment: If you need to build everything a `mvn clean package` is sufficient. No need to do `mvn clean install`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can skip the execution of the `maven-install-plugin` inside each of your `war` projects, using the [`skip`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html#skip) attribute. It is this plugin that is responsible for copying the produced artifact into the local repository.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can also do this :

```
<plugin> 
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
           </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```